# I am getting an error in my application that is related to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I set the path?

I get the following error when I run my rails application:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"practice"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is my index.erb.html file

```
<h3>Please fill the following details</h3>
<hr>
<%= form_with scope: :welcome , local: true do |f| -%>
<b><i>Name</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp<%= f.text_field :name %> </br></br>
<b><i>Address</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp <%= f.text_area :address %> </br></br>
<b><i>City</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp <%= f.text_field :city %> </br></br>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn-submit" %>

<% end %>
```

And this is my routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :practice

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This my Controller file:

```
class PracticeController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @welcome= Welcome.new;
    end

    def index
         @welcome= Welcome.new;
    end
    def show
         @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        @welcome=Welcome.new(params.require(:welcome).permit(:name,:address,:city)) ;
            if @welcome.save
            flash[:notice]="Successfully Registered"
            redirect_to practice_path
            else
            flash[:notice]="Error while registering"
            render:new
        end
    end
end
```

This is my show.html.erb file:

```html
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @welcome.name %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @Welcome.address %>
</p>

<p>
 <strong>City:</strong>
 <%= @welcome.city%>
</p>
```

I have not set any link_to helper for the show.html.erb file.

Comment: The practice#show route is waiting for an id in the params, how are you making the redirection to this route, through the form? any link_to helper?

Comment: `.../practice/123`. 123 is ur practice id.

Comment: how are you accessing index routes from browser?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes through form

Comment: @Mohanraj yes..

Answer (score 0):

When declaring routes use the plural form:

```
# bad
resources :practice

# good
resources :practices
```

To redirect to the index path you need to redirect to `practices_path`:

```
def create
  @welcome = Welcome.new(practice_params)
  if @welcome.save
    redirect_to practices_path, notice: "Successfully Registered"
  else
    render :new, notice: "Error while registering"
  end
end

private

def practice_params
  params.require(:welcome).permit(:name,:address,:city)
end
```

If you instead want to redirect to the newly created record just pass it to `redirect_to`:

```
redirect_to @welcome, notice: "Successfully Registered"
```

You can see the full list of routes with `rails routes` (In Rails 4 run `bundle exec rake routes` instead)

Comment: Also Ruby is not like C, Java or PHP. Semicolons (`;`) are only needed when you need to put multiple statements on the same line.

Comment: What path where you redirected to? `/practices`? Did you fix the `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I did changes in Controller create method. Now its working.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.